# CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints() off by 1 point per line in table view

Tags: macos, nstableview

I am attempting to use CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints() with tableview:heightOfRow:, feeding in an attributed string with the NSTableView's cell's attributes. The issue is that it's returning values in multiples of 13.0 (13.0 for 1 line, 26.0 for two lines, etc) instead of the expected multiples of 14.0 (which correspond's to [tableView rowHeight].

```
NSDictionary * attributes = [[[[[tableView tableColumnWithIdentifier: @"Message"] dataCell] attributedStringValue]
                attributesAtIndex: 0 effectiveRange: NULL] retain];
NSAttributedString * attributedMessage = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: message attributes: attributes];
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attributedMessage);

CFRange range;
CGSize size = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, [attributedMessage length]), NULL, CGSizeMake([column width], CGFLOAT_MAX), &range);
CFRelease(framesetter);
[attributedMessage release];
return size.height;
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Right now I'm hacking around it by hardcoding an increase of one point per line (13.0), but I'd like to do this the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar issue, and found that by tweaking the constraints rect I can get the output I desire.

In my case:

```
CGSize s1 = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(self.framesetter, rangeToSize, NULL, CGSizeMake(size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX), NULL);
CGSize s2 = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(self.framesetter, rangeToSize, NULL, CGSizeMake(size.width, 100000), NULL);
```

`s1` ends up as `{100, 23}`, `s2` ends up as `{100, 24}` (WTF?!).

Try replacing `CGSizeMake([column width], CGFLOAT_MAX)` with `CGSizeMake([column width], 10000)`